# strings comparison operations

Tags: c, arrays, string, string-comparison

i just started learning character arrays in `c`. i am just looking at the example `10.4` mentioned in `c programming by kochan`.

```
// Function to determine if two strings are equal
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
bool equalStrings (const char s1[], const char s2[])
{
  int i=0;
  bool areEqual;
  while ( s1[i] == s2 [i] && s1[i] != '\0' && s2[i] != '\0' )
          ++i;
  if ( s1[i] == '\0' && s2[i] == '\0' )
          areEqual = true;
  else
      areEqual = false;

  return areEqual;
}
int main (void) {
  bool equalStrings (const char s1[], const char s2[]); 
  const char stra[] = "string compare test";
  const char strb[] = "string";
  printf ("%i\n", equalStrings (stra, strb)); 
  printf ("%i\n", equalStrings (stra, stra)); 
  printf ("%i\n", equalStrings (strb, "string"));
  return 0;
}
```

i have a few questions about the string equality itself

1. In the above program, they just started comparing both the characters in the string. **doesn't it mean that if two strings are equal, they should be of same length?**. if yes, why didn't they compare the length first before they dived into comparing the characters?
2. does strings have any other comparison operations?. when i googled, i got things like strings similarity, strings identical or not. Any explanation about them would be great.

Comment: I looked into that book, and I wouldn't recommend as a sole source for learning C. The author does not mention the concept of **undefined behaviour** at all, and uses some dubious concepts.

Comment: do you have any other recommendations? @AnttiHaapala

Comment: I haven't read a C book in a while, but took a glimpse in the book since you mentioned its name. Tome it feels that the book does not mention any of the pitfalls at all, instead avoiding them or using imprecise language when describing certain aspects of C.

Comment: that's true. i have got some questions, when i asked them in stackoverflow. turns out the author didn't even mention some things @AnttiHaapala

Answer (score 2):

They didn't need to compare the length because these strings are null-terminated.  So, if you get to the end of either string, and you have reached the end of the other string too, they must therefore be the same length.

In C's string library, there are other comparison functions.  The most common are [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) and [`strncmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp).  They will tell you whether strings or substrings are equal, less than or greater than eachother (using an ordering based on actual integer values of each character).

Comment: that's true both have null-terminators. but wouldn't the lengths of `stra` and `strb` be different?

Comment: No.  Whenever you successfully match a character, you increment `i`.  If you hit a terminator, the strings are determined to be equal by this: `if ( s1[i] == '\0' && s2[i] == '\0' )`.  Now do you understand what I said in my answer?  I don't want to paraphrase myself a third time.  I was hoping that the way I explained it the first time was really clear.

Comment: alright that makes sense. thank you @paddy. i just started learning these things, so i didn't get what you said the first time. i guess stackoverflow is not for newbies then.

Comment: Sorry if I was impatient.  Probably means I'm tired and need to stop answering questions. =)

Comment: no problem @paddy. it's frustrating to the least when you got stuck learning. thank you for your help

Comment: Keep at it.  Learning to code takes time and repetition.  Lots and lots of both.  Kind of an endless amount of both.

Answer (score 1):

In order to know the length you gave iterate over the string. Give this, it is possible to figure out if they are not equal  faster than calculating the length first.

Comment: so that must be the reason why they chose not to compare the length because it'll take the same time to compare the characters in both the strings?

Comment: It could potentially take less time.